# Conflict IoC Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, constructor

I have the following codes:

Chat Staff Service

```
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatStaffService extends Service
{

     private $chatService;

     public function __construct(ChatService $chatService)
     {
         $this->chatService = $chatService;
     }

     ...
}
```

Chat Service

```
namespace Chat\Api\V1\Services\Chat;

class ChatService extends Service
{
     private $chatStaffService;

     public function __construct(ChatStaffService $chatStaffService)
     {

         $this->chatStaffService = $chatStaffService;
     }

     ...
}
```

What is going on:
In developing an API at some point I use ChatStaffService functions in ChatService and at other times I need to use ChatService functions in ChatStaffService. When I put dependency on any of the constructors the application simply stops and returns error 500. When I remove the dependency and try to use a function that does not need it everything returns to normal operation.

I need some idea to get around this problem. I tried to develop the following function to solve the problem but it did not work.

```
     function checkAndInject($anInstance, $injection)
     {
         if($anInstance == true)
            return $injection;
         else
            return \App::make($injection);
     }
```

Comment: You've introduced unnecessary coupling by making 2 classes that should have some sort of overlapping functionality dependent on each other. See if you can abstract a superclass and then let your current `ChatService` and `StaffChatService` extend that superclass.

Comment: It's an option, but does it have some more elegant solution?

Comment: Define "elegant"? Most of the software engineers I know would describe my solution as elegant ;) Joking aside, I can't really think of any other solution without introducing bad practices.

Comment: Maybe drop the methods `ChatService` has which `StaffChatService` needs and the methods `StaffChatService` has which `ChatService` needs into a trait?